# PHP restoring data in the case of failed migration

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, migration, alter-table

I've a table with suppliers what has the following structure:

[image]

Pay attention to provider field. It's a `VARCHAR` now. I've got to support this system from another developer and now  we need to have the list of providers and store additional info so I created another table for storing providers actually.

It has the following structure:  **id, name , margin, outer_name, etc.**

I plan to change type of provider to `INT(32)` and it will point to provider table.

The problem is that MySQL doesn't support transactions for changing the structure of database.

If I changed type of field from string to integer I lose all previous data. IF something goes wrong in the middle. I'm lost.

Would it be ok  dump data to file using serialisation and reading them from there?

Are there any better ways to do it?

Comment: safest method: mysqldump to file, edit the file to change the field definition, save to separate dump file. load the modfied dump, and if somethign blows up, you've got the original dump as a fallback.

Comment: Could you not add an additional field, say provider_id, that references your new table structure, perform your migration and essentially run both systems side by side.  Once you are happy there are no issues (entries have value in both fields maybe?) remove or blank the old 'provider' field.

Comment: Graeme, looks like the easiest solution for me. No need to create a new table.  Probably it would be necessary to create a new table for more complext situations but exactly in this case I see no necessity. If you post it as answer ,I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps to migrate data to new table and alter column.

**1. Insert all data into new table (Provider Table)**

```
INSERT INTO providerTable (NAME) 
SELECT DISTINCT provider
FROM suppliers;
```

**2. Update providerID into Main (Supplier) table**

```
UPDATE suppliers s 
INNER JOIN providerTable p ON s.provider = p.name 
SET s.provider = p.id;
```

Before altering the table please verify your data into supplier table.

**3. Then alter column datatype of Main (Supplier) table**

```
ALTER TABLE suppliers CHANGE provider provider INT(4) NOT NULL
```

Using this approach you don't need to take backup of table. You won't loss any data.